# Make return statement wait until bg work finishes

Tags: android, kotlin, asynchronous

This method is intended to get data from server and return them.
`requestGroups()` method in my code calls `execute()` method of third party library. `execute()` launches background executor that adds data to my list, but it returns empty list, because data adding to list occurs in the background and return happens immediately after executor lauching. How can I make return statement wait until all data are added to the list?

RepositoryImpl.kt:

```
class RepositoryImpl : Repository {

    override fun requestGroups(): List<VKGroup> {
        val vkGroups = mutableListOf<VKGroup>()
        VK.execute(GroupsService().groupsGetExtended(), object : // execute launches executor...
            VKApiCallback<GroupsGetObjectExtendedResponse> {
            override fun success(result: GroupsGetObjectExtendedResponse) {
                val groups = result.items
                Log.d(TAG, "result groups in repo: ${groups}")
                if (groups.isNotEmpty()) {
                    groups.forEach { group ->
                        vkGroups.add(
                            VKGroup(
                                id = group.id.value,
                                name = group.name ?: "",
                                photo = group.photo200 ?: ""
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "vkGroups in repo: ${vkGroups}")
            }

            override fun fail(error: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, error.toString())
            }
        })
        Log.d(TAG, "vkGroups in repo before return: ${vkGroups}")
        return vkGroups //and immediately returns empty list
    }
}
```

Third party execute function:

```
    /**
     * Execute api request with callback
     * You can use this method in UI thread
     * Also you can use your own async mechanism, like coroutines or RX
     */
    @JvmStatic
    fun <T>execute(request: ApiCommand<T>, callback: VKApiCallback<T>? = null) {
        VKScheduler.networkExecutor.submit {
            try {
                val result = executeSync(request)
                VKScheduler.runOnMainThread(Runnable {
                    callback?.success(result)
                })
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                VKScheduler.runOnMainThread(Runnable {
                    if (e is VKApiExecutionException && e.isInvalidCredentialsError) {
                        handleTokenExpired()
                    }
                    callback?.fail(e)
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes your function immediately returns. That is normal. If you want to do something with the response of the server than call that code in onsucces or onfail.

Comment: The problem is I want to return list with data, but success and fail are void and do not return anything.

Comment: In onsuccess you can call a/your function  that can handle the data in the list. Redesign your app. You can also add a Callback parameter to your requestGroups. Make requestGroups void. Redesign your code sequence. Make it suitable for asynchronizity.